# Modify Config file when User Control is added to form

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, user-controls

I have built a User Control library that has a reference to a WCF service. I would like to add the WCF Configuration information to the app.config file of the host project, which will be a Windows Forms app, when the User Control is dropped onto the Form. Is there a good way to do this? My thought is that in the control's load event I could add the necessary section to the config file.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to update a host application's config file, when the host app adds the User Control. This of course would be at design time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can update the config file programmatically. 
[Trouble writing programmatic config changes for WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380697/trouble-writing-programmatic-config-changes-for-wcf)

Comment: Ok, this looks like it will work. But I am still trying to figure out what event/interface to use with User Control, so that this code will fire at Design time...

Comment: My understanding of the way that works is that when you add the control to your form at design time, Visual Studio will instantiate your control. Therefore I suspect that you could fire off this code from the constructor.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I don't want to put it in the constructor because that will fire at runtime.  I think I need to implement an interface from System.ComponentModel.Design. I'm not sure which one yet, but I'm getting there. Thank you for getting me on track. :)

Comment: No problem. You could also use a static constructor (so it would only fire once), and check the config to see if the section is there before writing it to prevent overwriting it. That way it would be "defined" at design time, and then at runtime it would not overwrite the section. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible to load any app.config file during design time user control load.  You can prevent the need to though by wrapping your user control load methods with:

```
private void myUserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.DesignMode)
        {
            //....stuff
        }            
    }
```